# What analytics service can I use to track user preferences?

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I am looking for a service (i.e. Google Analytics, Fabric, Firebase) that I can use for mobile apps that allows me to track how many users choose certain options in as their preferences.

For example in the app there is a Settings screen that allows the user to choose color theme: Dark or Light.  I want to know at a given time, how many of my users chose Dark and how many chose Light.

I tried sending **events** to Google Analytics each time the user changes his preference, but I don't think it is the correct way, because it does not overwrite the existing value, and there can be duplicates (multiple events for the same option).

Answer (score 0):

In Google Analytics you can use [user scope custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#example-user). In Firebase Analytics you can use [user properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties).

Using GA for app tracking is not necessarily future proof, since Google is pushing towards Firebase.